# Tensorflow not building

Tags: bazel, syntaxnet

I followed the instructions given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#installation) to set-up my machine to run SyntaxNet. I have installed all the required software and ensured the versions are the same as the instructions. But when I run the bazel tests using command `bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...` on my Mac OS, it fails every time. I'm getting the following error message

`Sending SIGTERM to previous Bazel server (pid=42104)... Sending SIGKILL to previous Bazel server process group (pid=42104)... Error: SIGKILL unsuccessful after 10s: Operation not permitted`

Not sure what's going wrong. Kindly advice